# VisualStudio.Net reference not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

- I create a new solution called "WordpressAutomation"
- I create a new project, a class library, called "WordpressAutomation" in this solution
- I create a new project, a unit test project, called WordpressTests in this solution
- I add a reference to the project WordpressAutomation in the project WordpressTests"

This should be ok, shouldn't it?

However, as can be seen from the screenshot, when adding this using line in a class in the project WordpressTests,
the reference doesn't work. Even though it is there, as can plainly be seen.

When entering "using", the class library "WordpressAutomation" doesn't appear among the alternatives.
And I get this error message when trying to run:

"The type or namespace "WordpressAutomation" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Why is this happening? The reference is clearly there?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0g5R.png

Comment: Don't use tinypic in stackoverflow I am not able to open it. use the SO own image uploader.

Comment: What namespaces does the WordpressAutomation project contribute? They do not need to look anything like the project name or assembly name.

Comment: What are target frameworks for both projects?

Comment: Go to the WordpressAutomation property and see what is the default namespace and try to use that one.

Comment: Namespaces: The classes in the WordpressAutomation project uses the namespace "WordpressAutomation" (the same) 

Target framework: .Net

- I'm not very familiar with VS - I'm used to Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your project isn't actually including the .cs files to compile; they are only shown for information (they should appear as solid files with the C# logo):

[image]

Right click on these files and include them in the project. Then check what namespace they declare inside them. At the moment, your WordpressAutomation project simply doesn't contain any types.

Comment: Ah. Simple and comprehensible. Thanks :-)

Comment: @OP: As an aside, I usually keep "show all files" turned off during development, only turning it on briefly to fix issues such as the one you've experienced.  This keeps you from seeing files that *should* be mostly irrelevant during development.  Toggle this feature using the 4th button from the right in the solution explorer window.